# XML Parsing with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-mobile, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an XML file with jQuery mobile. Here is my jQuery script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "bars.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('bar').each(function(){
                    var date = new Date();
                    var day = date.getDay();
                    var name = $(this).attr('name');
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var specials = $(this).find('specials').text();
                    if (id == day)
                    {   
                        $('<li data-role="list-divider" id="link_'+id+'"></li>').html(name).appendTo('#daily-specials');
                        $('<li class="specials"></li>').html(specials).appendTo('#link_'+id);
                        }
                    });
                }); 
            });
        });
 </script>
```

And my XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<bars>
    <!-- Friday specials for bar one -->
    <bar name="Bar One" id="5">
       <specials>
         Special 1 <br />
         Special 2 <br />
         Special 3 <br />
         Special 4 <br />
         Special 5
       </specials>
   </bar>
   <!-- Saturday specials for bar one -->
    <bar name="Bar One" id="6">
       <specials>
         Special 1 <br />
         Special 2 <br />
         Special 3 <br />
         Special 4 <br />
         Special 5
       </specials>
   </bar>
</bars>
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? As you can see, I am trying to grab the special of "Bar One" for the current day of the week and then pass that information to HTML classes on my page. Nothing prints out on my website though. I apologize if I'm not even close but and direction would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: You have to pass an index and element to the each function as in: $(xml).find('bar').each(function(index, barInstance) [...]
then just access it
var specials = barInstance.find('specials').text();

Comment: Well, it works for me http://jsfiddle.net/c3pnc/

Comment: if all the bar have same description ; "name = bar One" then why you want search based on that .....??? you can search your data with each bar in each loop!!!

Comment: try to use  $.parseXML( xml )

Comment: Did you run it on a sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, or thursday?

Comment: This might be helpful
http://codeforbrowser.com/blog/parse-an-rss-feed-with-jquery/

Demo is added too...

Answer (score 0):

As you say nothing prints on the website.
I see that you are taking a local xml file. Same origin policy may be affecting.
I guess you are using chrome browser. (see the console for errors using F12 key on chrome.)

Try it on firefox or IE.

If you still want to use chrome.. go for adding below in your targer property of chrome shortcut.
    --allow-file-access-from-files

Hope this helps & you mark it as answer.